# Finding an Orthogonal Transformation with 2 given vectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

There are two possible orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that leave the origin fixed and send the point $(0,13)$ to $(5,12)$. Find their matrices and describe them geographically.

Can anyone explain to me how I'd go about working this out? Sorry but I know nothing about orthogonal transformations and nowhere seems to explain how I can work them out well enough...

Comment: See [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrices#Elementary_constructions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the action on a basis.

You want $ (0,1) $ to get mapped to $( \frac{5}{13}, \frac {12}{13})$.
Since you want an orthogonal transformation, $(1,0)$ gets mapped to $(-\frac{12}{13}, \frac{5}{13})$.

Which matrix does this>

Comment: are the matrices
[cos(22.6) sin(22.6), -sin(22.6) cos(22.6)]
and
[cos(22.6) -sin(22.6), sin(22.6) cos(22.6)]

got them by using the y=Ax equation and replacing the y and x variables with their column vectors

Comment: Well, you could simply use the fractions above, instead of converting them over to $\sin \theta$. The rotation matrix gives you the general form (for 2-D). In this case, because we know exactly what we want, we can specify the exact entries of the matrix, instead of dealing with rounding errors.